# window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSER__ is undefined in Electron app

Tags: javascript, redux, react-redux, electron, redux-devtools-extension

Trying to get redux-devtools-extension working on my Redux app that's packed by Electron.

I'm using electron v5.0.7, electron-devtools-installer v2.2.4

If I boot up the Electron app locally (within Electron), and I look at the Redux section in devtools, it'll give me an error "No store found. Make sure to follow the instructions." If I access the web version of this electron app through localhost, I am able to see the redux-devtools working.

Here's how my main.js for Electron is installing the extension using electron-devtools-installer, per their [documentation](https://github.com/MarshallOfSound/electron-devtools-installer):

```
app.on('ready', () => {
  createWindow();
  if (serve) {
    try {
      const { 
        default: installExtension,
        REDUX_DEVTOOLS
      } = require('electron-devtools-installer');

      installExtension(REDUX_DEVTOOLS)
        .then((name) => console.log(`Added Extension:  ${name}`))
        .catch((err) => console.log('An error occurred: ', err));
    } catch (e) {
      log.error('ERROR FROM ADDING DEVTOOLS: ', e);
    }
  }
});
```

When my Electron window opens, it logs `Added Extension: Redux DevTools`

Here's how I'm adding the redux-devtools to my store per their [documentation](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension):

```
import {
  createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose,
} from 'redux';
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { UserSettings, CurrentViewedAccount } from './ducks/index';

const composeEnhancers = typeof window === 'object' && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__
  ? window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({
    // Specify extension’s options like name, actionsBlacklist, actionsCreators, serialize...
  })
  : compose;

const enhancer = composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  UserSettings: UserSettings.default,
  CurrentViewedAccount: CurrentViewedAccount.default,
});

const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  return appReducer(state, action);
};

const store = createStore(rootReducer, enhancer);

export default store;
```

When I try to see what is on the window in the store, **REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE** is undefined.

It seems like there's a disconnect when this is being run inside Electron, since it is working as a plain web app. I'm curious to know if anybody was able to get it working?

Comment: It is possible that this is impossible right now - https://github.com/MarshallOfSound/electron-devtools-installer/issues/65
https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension/issues/219